# How to avoid multiple echo's of a certain php section?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, echo

I am busy creating a website that gives users the possibility to host dinners and to join dinners by strangers. I am currently working on the page that shows the dinner a certain user has entered. I have used this code to display all the necessary details about the dinner and the user:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];  

$sql =  "SELECT g.straatnaam, g.huisnummer, g.woonplaats, 
               g.voornaam, g.email, d.tijd, d.datum, d.gerecht, d.capaciteit, d.prijs
        FROM gebruikers g
        INNER JOIN diner d on g.id = d.gebruikersid
        WHERE g.id='$id' ";

mysql_select_db('nassen_database');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $adres =  $row['adres'];
  $woonplaats = $row['woonplaats'];
  $voornaam = $row['voornaam'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $gerecht =  $row['gerecht'];
  $capaciteit = $row['capaciteit'];
  $prijs = $row['prijs'];  
  $tijd = $row['tijd'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];

  echo "<ul>";
    echo "<h3> Eetprofiel van " .$row['voornaam'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Woonplaats: " .$row['woonplaats']. "</li>";
    echo "<li> Adres: " .$row['straatnaam']. " " .$row['huisnummer']. "</li>"; 
    echo "<li> Meld je aan door een mailtje te sturen naar " .$row['email'].  "</li>";

    echo "<h3> Op het menu staat " .$row['gerecht'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Het diner vindt plaats op " .$row['datum']. " om " .$row['tijd']. " uur </li>";
    echo "<li> Capaciteit: " .$row['capaciteit']. " personen</li>";
    echo "<li> Het kost " .$row['prijs']. " credits </li>";
echo "</ul>"; 
}

mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
```

The code works perfect, but when one user has submitted two dinners, the user's address and city are displayed twice as well. I want to display the user's address, e-mail and city only once (called straat, huisnummer, woonplaats, email and voornaam in this code).

I get this result right now:

[image: I get this result right now]

I want the "Eetprofiel van Pram" to only be displayed once and both of the "Op het Menu Staat..." to be displayed. How can I change my code in order to get that?

Comment: echo `<ul>` outside the loop

Comment: use [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead if [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated in php 5.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only show one user's dinner at a time, you can use a boolean variable to signal if the current iteration is the first, and print the user's data only in that case

```
$first = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  echo "<ul>";

  if($first){
    echo "<h3> Eetprofiel van " .$row['voornaam'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Woonplaats: " .$row['woonplaats']. "</li>";
    echo "<li> Adres: " .$row['straatnaam']. " " .$row['huisnummer']. "</li>"; 
    echo "<li> Meld je aan door een mailtje te sturen naar " .$row['email'].  "</li>";
    $first = false;
  }

  $adres =  $row['adres'];
  $woonplaats = $row['woonplaats'];
  $voornaam = $row['voornaam'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $gerecht =  $row['gerecht'];
  $capaciteit = $row['capaciteit'];
  $prijs = $row['prijs'];  
  $tijd = $row['tijd'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];



  echo "<h3> Op het menu staat " .$row['gerecht'].  "</h3>";
  echo "<li> Het diner vindt plaats op " .$row['datum']. " om " .$row['tijd']. " uur </li>";
  echo "<li> Capaciteit: " .$row['capaciteit']. " personen</li>";
  echo "<li> Het kost " .$row['prijs']. " credits </li>";
  echo "</ul>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, user data should be stored in a different table and fetched separately. Now for your particular issue, you could either fetch user data separately once and ignore it in the while() loop, or use a conditional statement like that:

```
$foo = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    $adres =    $row['adres'];
    $woonplaats = $row['woonplaats'];
    $voornaam = $row['voornaam'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $gerecht =  $row['gerecht'];
    $capaciteit = $row['capaciteit'];
    $prijs = $row['prijs']; 
    $tijd = $row['tijd'];
    $datum = $row['datum'];

    if($foo == 1) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<h3> Eetprofiel van " .$row['voornaam'].  "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Woonplaats: " .$row['woonplaats']. "</li>";
    echo "<li> Adres: " .$row['straatnaam']. " " .$row['huisnummer']. "</li>"; 
    echo "<li> Meld je aan door een mailtje te sturen naar " .$row['email'].    "</li>";
    $foo = 0;
    }
    echo "<h3> Op het menu staat " .$row['gerecht'].    "</h3>";
    echo "<li> Het diner vindt plaats op " .$row['datum']. " om " .$row['tijd']. " uur </li>";
    echo "<li> Capaciteit: " .$row['capaciteit']. " personen</li>";
    echo "<li> Het kost " .$row['prijs']. " credits </li>";
    echo "</ul>"; 
}
```